# gridsvg does not work when used inside a function

Tags: r, svg, ggplot2, r-grid

I want to define a plot saving function that uses the gridsvg device from the package gridSVG.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)    
mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear,levels=c(3,4,5),
                      labels=c("3gears","4gears","5gears")) 
mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am,levels=c(0,1),
                    labels=c("Automatic","Manual")) 
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl,levels=c(4,6,8),
                     labels=c("4cyl","6cyl","8cyl")) 

myPlot <- qplot(mpg, data=mtcars, geom="density", fill=gear, alpha=I(.5), 
       main="Distribution of Gas Milage", xlab="Miles Per Gallon", 
       ylab="Density")

savePlot <- function(filename, plot, plotWidth = 15, plotHeight = 10){
    gridSVG:::gridsvg(name = filename, width = plotWidth, height = plotHeight)
    print(plot)
    dev.off(which = dev.cur())
}
```

However if I then try to use the function it does not work. An error results:

```
savePlot("~/Desktop/myplot.svg", myPlot)
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'filename' not found
```

However if I do those steps from the console it works:

```
gridSVG::gridsvg(name = "~/Desktop/myPlot.svg", width = 15, height = 10)
myPlot
dev.off()
```

Is there a way I might be able to use the gridsvg function from within another function?

I wonder if I might be able to do it with eval from some environment.

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: How curious! `gridsvg` has a bunch of `eval(fncall[[i]])` that seem to be causing the issue, but you would have thought that the named arguments get filtered down to the right environment?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a roundabout, but slightly more principled, way without sticking everything in the global environment (inspired by the scoping discussion in [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)):

```
library(gridSVG)

savePlot <- function(filename, plot, plotWidth = 15, plotHeight = 10){
    gridsvg(sys.frame(1))
    print(plot)
    grid.export(filename)
    grDevices::dev.off(which = dev.cur())
}
```

`sys.frame(1)` gives us the evaluation frame of the parent context (there's an ok explanation [here](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-lang/R-lang_53.html) for all variations on functions that access the call stack).

I separated out the call to `grid.export()` from the call to `dev.off()`, because essentially all the `dev.off` from gridSVG does is call `grid.export`, then call the `grDevices::dev.off`. This also lets us explicitly feed the file name to `grid.export`.

Answer (score 2):

How curious. `gridsvg` seems to have an `eval(fncall[[i]])` step where it walks through all the arguments and assigns them, and it must be looking in the wrong environment or something?? I am not sure if this is a problem with the `gridSVG` package; `eval`-semantics always confuse me.

Here's a workaround: if you make sure the argument -values- get passed to `gridsvg` (rather than the argument names) it works, though I agree this isn't particularly elegant. And you have to explicitly `library(gridSVG)`.

```
library(gridSVG)
savePlot <- function(filename, plot, plotWidth = 15, plotHeight = 10){
    eval(call('gridsvg', name=filename, width=plotWidth, height=plotHeight))
    print(plot)
    dev.off(which = dev.cur())
}
```

All it does is essentially call `gridsvg` with `width=15` rather than `width=plotWidth` and so on.